# Не работает свойство background SASS

Tags: html, css, sass

```
.mobile 
    min-height: 864px
    padding: 48px 0 79px 0
    background: url('../img/mobile_app.png') center (center / cover) no repeat
    &_item 
      width: 320px
      height: 280px
      margin: 0 auto
      &_1
        background: url('../img/mobile_screen1.png') center (center / cover) no repeat
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.mobile 
    min-height: 864px
    padding: 48px 0 79px 0
    background: url('../img/mobile_app.png') center center / cover no-repeat
    &_item 
      width: 320px
      height: 280px
      margin: 0 auto
      &_1
        background: url('../img/mobile_screen1.png') center center / cover no-repeat
```